# TAR error — `wp-content: file changed as we read it`

Tags: tar

#### Background

I have a bash alias I use to back up a Wordpress home folder.
The command is run from `/home/waiheke26/sites/www.DOMAIN.co.nz/public`

The command is:

```
tar --exclude='./wp-content/uploads' \
    --exclude='./wp-content/cache' \
    --exclude ='./cache' \
    --exclude='./wp-content/backups' \
    --exclude='./wp-snapshots' \
    --exclude='./wp-content/envato-backups' \
    -zcf \
    /home/waiheke26/sites/www.DOMAIN.co.nz/backups/wp-files-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).tar.gz \
    . \ 
    && echo "File backup OK" || echo "File backup failed"';
```

#### The Issue

Recently, when I run the command I get the error:

```
tar: ./wp-content: file changed as we read it
File backup failed
```

Much of what I've seen online regarding this `file changed as we read it` error suggests it is because the user is creating the tar file within the directory being archived. In my case that does not apply, as the tar file is being created elsewhere.

#### Question

How can I determine the cause of this error?

Comment: Start exactly from the point where the Error Message is telling you: something might be modifying the `wp-content/` Directory while the `tar` _Tape Archiver_ is working. Shut down your Full Stack or run your `tar` Command from an Environment where nothing is running - for instance, from another User Account - and check again if you get the same Error Message.

Comment: Thanks. Not currently in a position to shut things down. Does that error mean the tar file creation will have aborted, or simply that whatever changed will not be archived?

Comment: Yep. Sometimes even pressing a mere `F5` Refresh Key has to be approved by a Dozen of Bosses around. So what about shutting things down? The Moon might suddenly collapse. Now that I think about it, it is complaining that _File changed as we read it_ and not that a Directory has been modified. Most likely, some File is in use and it does not want to read it, because it could be partly modified when it finishes reading it. As the Final Error Message is stating (_File backup failed_), I think that everything got cancelled. Try to find a Force Switch such as (`--force`) or something.

Comment: Thanks for that. Actually, the "backup failed" message is something my bash command is generating (you'll see it in the command), so is not something tar is outputting. Based on what you've said, I suspect the backup is fine, except that a file (or a few) may have changed whilst backup was taking place. As all essential WordPress files and assets are static, I suspect I can safely assume the backup is fine (e.g., it could be safely used for a restore). Although I'd still be curious to know what file is actually changing.

Comment: I would search on the Internet or read the `tar` Manual Page using either the `tar --help` Command or the `man tar` Command and see if that `tar: ./wp-content: file changed as we read it` Character String is an Error Message or a Warning Message. If it is a Warning Message, then you do not have to worry about anything. Otherwise, I would install a File-Manager Software Application such as _Midnight Commander_ and manually inspect the `tar` Archive File to see if _at least_ it is looking all right. More than that, I would search for a Tool that is able to compare Directories recursively.

Comment: This article https://linux.m2osw.com/tar-publichtmlwp-content-file-changed-we-read-it suggests that the error could be due to a conflict with wp_cron.php. It makes sense that _something_ is conflicting. So far I haven't been able to confirm what, but I'm going to try the suggestion to slightly change the time that the tar backup job runs.

Answer (score 1):

*So, sidestepping digging into what is changing wp-content while tar is working for a moment because of the stated sensitivity of your env.. which, speculatively, i might mess with watching `lsof` during the operation.*

If you can spare the space in your environment, you can keep an "offline" copy of your public up to date using something like this:

`rsync -va /home/asdf/public/ /home/asdf/backups/public/ --delete`

It will run quickly after the initial copy, because it will only copy diffs. You could consider adding `--exclude` options here to save the work of copying files you will exclude from the archive anyway.

Then, make your tar archive as before, backups/public as source:

```
tar --exclude='./whatever' \
    -zcf \
    /home/asdf/backups/wp-files-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).tar.gz \
    /home/asdf/backups/public \ 
    && echo "File backup OK" || echo "File backup failed"';
```

This effectively gives `tar` an environment where nothing will change while it's running, as others have suggested.

Comment: Great. Thank you Bitless. This is **very** helpful. I'll set up things in the way you've suggested, as I can see how this will avoid the issue, and provide a more stable source for the TAR. Also, thanks for improving the readability of the code in my question.